# Calculating area for a weird shaped numerical curve

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, interpolation

I have a numerical data by this code

```
data=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode@
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiZrp.png"],"Byte"]]]
```

And I want to find the area of that shape as shown in the figure. How do I approach this problem in Mathematica? The issue is that length at say 50 and 50.5 can be very different.

[image]

What I tried to do was to negate the y values and align the horizontal as zero, so that Interpolation would do the job. Any clever ideas?

Comment: Is this question about software *Mathematica* or about signal processing? In its current form this question may be more appropriate for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yes Alexey , How to do this in mathematica

Comment: I have mentioned that

Comment: How to you exactly define "the area here"?

Answer (score 6):

There are many anwsers already, but i want to point out a (in my opinion) simpler approach. Just use Mathematicas [`Area`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html) build-in.

(Your data is in `data`)

```
lineHeight = 0.55;
sData = {{data[[-1, 1]], lineHeight}, {data[[1, 1]], lineHeight}}~ Join~data;
(*append data with edgepoints*)
sData[[All, 2]] = Min[lineHeight, #] & /@ sData[[All, 2]];
(*comment this line if you wan to have no clipping*)
poly = Polygon[sData]; (*make the polygon*)
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, Epilog -> {Gray, poly}, ImageSize -> Large]
(*plot it*)
Area@poly (*calc the area*)
```

With clipping:

> [image]
>   0.00392424

Without clipping:

> [image]
>   0.00626118

BTW: an interpolation can add more unwanted area because it smoothes between the points. Its on your behalf to decide if you want that.

Comment: Thank you very much, Julien Kluge , This is exactly what I want

Comment: @ Julien, When use Needs["polytopes`"]. It loads successfully but Area function is in red color? and whenever I compute this, the system crashes

Comment: What version are you using, @TM90? `Area[]` has been built-in since version 10. What are you using the Polytopes package for?

Comment: @ J.M 11.0 version. When I tried  to do this even without polytopes, it had been crashing

Comment: What is polytopes for? The code should work out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Writing:

```
data = {{50., 0.55403}, ..., {50.5, 0.553796}};
bar = 0.56;

ListLinePlot[{data, {{First[data][[1]], bar}, {Last[data][[1]], bar}}}, 
             PlotRange -> All, 
             Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
             AxesLabel -> {x, y} 
            ] 

Integrate[1, 
         {x, First[data][[1]], Last[data][[1]]}, 
         {y, Min[Interpolation[data][x], bar], Max[Interpolation[data][x], bar]}
         ] // N
```

I get:

[image]

> 0.00677696008549726

which are the graph and the desired area.

Comment: @ Manu This is not what I want, The thing you showed is just area under the curve. what I need is the area I mentioned between the curve and the straight line.

Comment: ,Thank you very much and I agree

Answer (score 3):

The line on your plot looks like

```
line[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[{{50, 0.56}, {50.5, 0.55}}, x];
SetAttributes[line, Listable]
```

And the data curve is

```
interpolant[x_] = Interpolation[data, x, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

So your plot is

```
Plot[{line[x], interpolant[x]},
 {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

First find which data points are near the roots between the difference of the curves. I take the longest sequence without sign changes and include the first occurrence of different sign in both ends, because the roots are between different signs:

```
roots = With[{Q = Length /@ SplitBy[line[data[[All, 1]]] - data[[All, 2]], Sign]},
           Accumulate[Q][[Join[# - 1, #]]] &[Ordering[Q, -1]] + {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Then the integration limits:

```
lims = x /. FindRoot[line[x] - interpolant[x], {x, data[[#, 1]], data[[#2, 1]]}] & @@@ roots
```

Result:

```
Integrate[line[x], {x, Sequence @@ lims}] -
 Integrate[interpolant[x], {x, Sequence @@ lims}]
```

> 0.0042779763

Comment: down vote? Would you please tell why..

Comment: Maybe the DV is because you don't use [Tai's Method](http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/17/2/152) :) But seriously, yours is a reasonable approach to a reasonable interpretation of the question. (What might deserve a DV is the question, which is not clear: It's impossible to tell which of the approaches posted give a correct answer.) -- BTW, you can get an antiderivative of a non-spline `InterpolatingFunction` more quickly than integrating it. Use `Integrate[interpolant[x], x]` or `Evaluate@Integrate[interpolant[#], #] &`. (Speed is not really important here, though.)

Comment: Okay, I upvoted, in part to offset the down vote. I have to say, the link from @MichaelE2 cracked me up. And I agree, the approach in this response seems fine.

Comment: @Coolwater, Thank you very much for your reply.This is more or less that I want.